# EditText text shows only after soft keyboard is gone

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext

When i click on a EditText and start writing on soft keyboard, letters doesn't show up while i am writing. Only when the keyboard is gone.

On the emulator i didn't have this problem. Tested on couple devices. All devices have the same problem.

On the first 2 EditTexts i don't have any problem. This problem only occurs on the 3rd and 4th EditTexts.

I've experimented on it with different kind of inputTypes. It didn't help. When i use another layout instead of constraint layout, it solves it. But i would like to keep using constraint layout.

````
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".RegisterActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_register"
        android:layout_width="149dp"
        android:layout_height="175dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logo_white_background"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText_reg_Name"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/register_name"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:inputType="text"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView_register" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText_reg_UserName"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/register_username"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:inputType="text"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText_reg_Name" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText_reg_Email"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/register_email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText_reg_UserName" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText_reg_Password"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/register_password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText_reg_Email" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_createAccount"
        android:layout_width="224dp"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:text="@string/register_createaccount"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText_reg_Password" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>```
````

Comment: Are you using AndroidX in your project if yes then use
androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout  this instead of  android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout this. It's working fine here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you had AndroidX Dependencies you can use this code

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/constraint"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView_register"
                    android:layout_width="149dp"
                    android:layout_height="175dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:src="#000000"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

            <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText_reg_Name"
                    android:layout_width="220dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="Name"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView_register"/>

            <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText_reg_UserName"
                    android:layout_width="220dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="Username"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText_reg_Name"/>

            <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText_reg_Email"
                    android:layout_width="220dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="Email"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText_reg_UserName"/>

            <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText_reg_Password"
                    android:layout_width="220dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="Password"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText_reg_Email"/>

            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_createAccount"
                    android:layout_width="224dp"
                    android:layout_height="34dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:text="Create Account"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText_reg_Password"/>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Else, remove AndroidX dependencies and just set **Support Dependency**

Comment: thank you so much. i just migrated to AndroidX and used your code. it solved my problem.